# Selenium not picking the value against the XPATH Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to automate this [link](https://www.ukparks.com/park/haighfield-park/) to get the email address with selenium. I have used this XPATH `//span[@class="emailhide"]/a/@href` which is perfectly find but selenium doesn't extract the value from there.

I also user Regex but it didn't work as well `re.findall(r'mailto:(.*?)\?sub', str(driver.page_source))`

Can anyone tell what's the issue here? why it's not getting the emails and how can I extract it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.ukparks.com/park/haighfield-park/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="emailhide"]'))
)

response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
email = response.xpath('//span[@class="emailhide"]/a/@href').get()
email_re = re.findall(r'mailto:(.*?)\?sub', str(driver.page_source))

print(email)
print(email_re)
```

Comment: What value did you want it to get?

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to populate the data after a click event on the a tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.ukparks.com/park/haighfield-park/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="emailhide"]/a'))).click()
link=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="emailhide"]/a'))).get_attribute("href")
print(link)
```

Output

```
mailto:haighfieldcp@aol.com?subject=Enquiry%20from%20UKParks.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the following to fetch email from that site using requests:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.ukparks.com/park/haighfield-park/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one(".detail-box").get_text(strip=True)
    email_raw = re.findall(r"ehArr\.push\('(.*?)'\);",item)
    email = ''.join(email_raw[::-1])
    print(email)
```

Output:

```
haighfieldcp@aol.com
```